# Scraping a background image in a div

Tags: php, css, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a background image inside a div to get the picture of a roller coaster.

The image isn't inside a `img` tag but rather a div with the link in the background-image property.

http://rcdb.com

```
<a id=rrc_pic></a>
```

HTML Render:

```
<a id="rrc_pic" href="/1519.htm#p=11769" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 6px 0px 0px; width: 188px; height: 244px; background-image: url("/aaarkrc");"></a>
```

**Code:**

```
              <?php 
              include("simple_html_dom.php"); // Web Scraping

                $html=file_get_html("https://rcdb.com/"); // Connect to Roller Coaster Database
                  foreach($html->find('img') as $element) // get picture of roller coaster
                  echo $element->src . '<br>';
              ?>
```

I also tried swapping out `img` with `a[class="rrc_pic"]`

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? What do you expect as a final result?

Comment: @krasipenkov  When you load http://rcdb.com it will give you a random roller coaster with the image. I'm trying to get that random image on refresh on a site. The image isn't in a `img` tag but it's a background image to an`a` tag.

Comment: The image on this site is loaded with JavaScript, so you can't "scrape" it with PHP without evaluating the client-side script on your server.

Comment: You should consider using a "command line browser" like e.g. phantomJS to do this before you find yourself trying to implement a browser subset yourself.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Ok. Is there a way to grab add the given url and use that to grab the image? Example: https://rcdb.com/aadeijc

Comment: Where div element